# Validation of a Django model using a foreign key set after saving the form

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do validate a model based on a value that I set after `save(commit=False)`. How can I achieve this? 
I have multiple forms (Item, Listing, Price) that I combine in one view and then create one instance after the other while saving.

**edit**: I'll try to explain a bit further. Every listing lists an item. Every item has a category. Every category has a minimum price. Listings have prices(can be multiple to retain a history). When the instance of Price is saved, I want to validate that the amount is greater than or equal to the minimum set for the category of the item referenced by the listing.

#### models.py

```py
...
class Category(models.Model):
  ...
class Item(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, ...)

class Listing(models.Model):
  for_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, ...)

class Price(models.Model):
  for_listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, ...)
  amount = MoneyField(...)

class MinPriceForCategory(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, ...)
  amount = MoneyField(...)
```

### views.py

````py
...
def add_item(self):
  ...
  # create form instances from request.POST etc
  ...
  item = form_item.save()
  listing = form_listing.save(commit=False)
  listing.for_item = item
  listing.save()

  # validation happens in the first call to save()
  price = form_price.save(commit=False)
  price.for_listing = listing
  # I need the validation to happen here so the instance of Listing is available
  price.save()
```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please elaborate a bit more of what your setting is, i.e. the context.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to validate, but if we're talking about model validation in django, then you'd probably want to take a look at the django model validators docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Well the question could be asked much broader: How can I validate a model with fields that are set after save() is called. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just found another way to do what I wanted, although I'm not sure if that's the right way. I now instantiate the form for the Model that depends on Listing and pass the instance of Listing to the the constructor:

```py
# views.py
...
form_listing = ListingForm(request.POST)
listing = form_listing.save()

form_price = PriceForm(request.POST, listing=listing)
if form_price.is_valid():
  price = form_price.save()


# forms.py

class PriceForm(forms.ModelForm):
  ...
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.listing = kwargs.pop('listing', None)
    super(PriceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```